# Passing multiple tags (or/and) via -Dcucumber.options does not trigger my test

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

i've bunch of scenarios with tagging @ABC and @DEF under module 'TEST'.

I'm able to run test with multiple tagging using following command (older way and soon to be deprecated)

```
mvn clean test -pl TEST -Dcucumber.options="--tags @ABC,@DEF"
```

but not

```
mvn clean test -pl TEST -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@ABC or @DEF'"
```

any idea?
i've also switching the quotes around but still doesn't work, no test are triggered.

what I've tried

-`Dcucumber.options='--tags @ABC or @DEF'` 
    `-Dcucumber.options='--tags "@ABC or @DEF"'` 
    `-Dcucumber.options="--tags '@ABC or @DEF'"`
    `-Dcucumber.options="--tags '(@ABC or @DEF)'"`

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the single quotes. Could you try `mvn clean test -pl TEST -Dcucumber.options="--tags @ABC or @DEF"`?

Note, for more information, see [Cucumber documentation on Tag expressions](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've tried as u suggested, it doesn't work either. as per the cucumber docs , they are also suggesting with quote.
`mvn test -Dcucumber.options='--tags "@smoke and @fast"'`

Comment: Yes, quotes around the options, but not around the tags themselves. The example given [here](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#list-configuration-options) is `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoke"`, so yours should be `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoke and @fast"`?

Answer (score 0):

In my environments (W10 and CentOS 7), the 3rd way that you listed is working for me.

-Dcucumber.options="--tags '@ABC or @DEF'"

My tests are their own module in our application project, so I execute a java class to run stuff (vs. maven test). For example on CentOS, I have a script with the line

java -ea -Dcucumber.options="${cucumberTags}"  regressionTests.AutomatedTest >> $logFile.log

I kick off the tests using a script, and it can be a little tricky buliding the "cucumberTags" string, and getting a literal single quote before the first and after the last tag, but this is definitely my working format.

-Dennis